# Htaccess rewrite rule directory based on caracters of a word

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

how can i rewrite to deeper directory structure based on request_url?? eg :

`%{REQUEST_URI}` = `/request_url.html`

and rewrite to match file in folder `/r/e/q/request_url.html`

some help???

Comment: Is that a single URL you want to rewrite? Or is part of it variable and you are wanting to rewrite many URLs?

Comment: yes sure i need the regex to rewrite based on the request_url to match the first second and 3th caracters this is for a caching directory with multiple levels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like the following at the top of your root `.htaccess` file using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^request_url\.html$ r/e/q/$0 [L]
```

The `$0` backreference contains the entire URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (saves repetition).

---

> **UPDATE:** this is not for only one URL need the regex to match the 3 first characters for deeper directory

Ok, assuming you are only matching `.html` URLs for the document root only (ie. single path segments) - all `.html` URLs in the document root. Then you could do something like the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^(.)([^/])([^/])[^/]*\.html$ $1/$2/$3/$0 [L]
```

Where `$1`, `$2` and `$3` are backreferences to the 1st, 2nd and 3rd characters of the URL-path requested. ie. The 1st, 2nd and 3rd parenthesised subpatterns (capturing groups) in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (regex).

The above matches `/request_url.html` and internally rewrites to `/r/e/q/request_url.html`. But it would fail to match `/foo/request_url.html` since it's not in the document root.

Comment: thanks but this is not for only one url need the regex to match the 3 first characters for deeper directory

Comment: @remi Is the initial request in the document root only? How do you differentiate this URL from any URL that should not be rewritten?

Comment: yes root only, the rewrite will be eg:  "request_url.html" to "cache_folder/r/e/q/request_url.html"

Comment: @remi I've updated my answer.

Comment: thanks for the help )))

Comment: @remi You're welcome :)